# drawRect see empty array

Tags: objective-c, ios, nsmutablearray, drawrect

Button in drawtestViewController.m is linked to pushPoint action in ChalkBoard.m. It populates pointArray with CGpoint objects. This array is full of objects everywhere, except when viewed from drawRect. It seems as from drawRect I'm somehow referencing the empty copy of original array, but I can not find any error ...

I have uploaded the whole project at http://dl.dropbox.com/u/42099382/drawtest.zip

---

Button action in drawtestViewController.m

```
- (IBAction)myDo {
   NSLog(@"-Button was pressed");    
  [self.board pushPoint:CGPointMake(100, 100 )];
  [self.board pushPoint:CGPointMake(10, 100 )];
  [self.graphicView setNeedsDisplay];
}
```

---

```
//  ChalkBoard.h
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ChalkBoard : UIView
-(void)pushPoint:(CGPoint)point;
@property (nonatomic,retain) NSMutableArray *pointArray;
@end
```

---

```
//ChalkBoard.m
#import "ChalkBoard.h"

@implementation ChalkBoard
@synthesize pointArray;

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        self.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    }
    return self;
}

-(NSMutableArray *)pointArray 
{
    if(pointArray == nil) pointArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithCapacity:10];
    return pointArray;
}

-(void)pushPoint:(CGPoint)point{
    // this is called from drawtestViewController.m by button press
    // in here the array is full and growing by each button press
    [self.pointArray addObject:[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:point]];
   NSLog(@"-pushPoint executed, size is %u, array: %@",[self.pointArray count], pointArray);
}

- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect{
// here array is always empty
NSLog(@"-DrawRect executed, size is %u, array: %@",[pointArray count], pointArray);
    if ([pointArray count] >1){   
       ... some irrelevant code
    }
}

@end
```

---

```
NSLog output

2012-04-09 11:34:39.145 drawtest[5260:f803] -DrawRect executed, size is 0, array: (null)
2012-04-09 11:34:41.261 drawtest[5260:f803] -Button was pressed
2012-04-09 11:34:41.262 drawtest[5260:f803] -pushPoint executed, size is 1, array: (
    "NSPoint: {100, 100}"
)
2012-04-09 11:34:41.264 drawtest[5260:f803] -pushPoint executed, size is 2, array: (
    "NSPoint: {100, 100}",
    "NSPoint: {10, 100}"
)
2012-04-09 11:34:41.266 drawtest[5260:f803] -DrawRect executed, size is 0, array: (null)
2012-04-09 11:34:42.825 drawtest[5260:f803] -Button was pressed
2012-04-09 11:34:42.826 drawtest[5260:f803] -pushPoint executed, size is 3, array: (
    "NSPoint: {100, 100}",
    "NSPoint: {10, 100}",
    "NSPoint: {100, 100}"
)
2012-04-09 11:34:42.827 drawtest[5260:f803] -pushPoint executed, size is 4, array: (
    "NSPoint: {100, 100}",
    "NSPoint: {10, 100}",
    "NSPoint: {100, 100}",
    "NSPoint: {10, 100}"
)
2012-04-09 11:34:42.829 drawtest[5260:f803] -DrawRect executed, size is 0, array: (null)
```

Comment: Could it be that you unintentionally have two different ChalkBoard objects?  One that's in the window so it gets drawn, the other that's connected to your `board` outlet, which gets the points pushed to it. Try logging `self` with "%p" in both methods.

Comment: I can not find anything like that :( I have uploaded the whole project at http://dl.dropbox.com/u/42099382/drawtest.zip

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is actually not in your `Chalkboard` class but in your `drawtestViewcontroller`. Your `myDo` action adds points to `self.board`, but sends the `setNeedsDisplay` message to `self.graphicView`, which is also a `Chalkboard` but not the same one that you added the points to.

So the second log message you're seeing actually comes from an entirely different object.

Answer (score 1):

Replace `pointArray` with `self.pointArray` everywhere in `drawRect` method.
When you use `pointArray` the variable is used as is (without the getter method invocation). When you use `self.pointArray` then the getter method is used.

I will also advice you to leave the getter and setter to the compiler to generate and initialize your pointArray in the init method.

Comment: added self, but no change 

    - (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect{
          NSLog(@"-DrawRect executed, size is %u, array: %@",[self.pointArray count], self.pointArray);
    }

Comment: Just to make you happy, your answer saved me after 10h of looking to my view :) Have a nice weekend!